# Proving triangle inequality

Tags: analysis

A metric is usually said to be a function $d: S^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (where $ S$ is some set), for which the following conditions hold:

$$(1) \: d (x, y)=d (y, x)$$

$$(2)\: d(x, y)=0 \Leftrightarrow  x=y$$

$$(3)\: d (x, z) \leq d (x, y)+d (y, z) $$

Given those, we can prove:
$$(4) \: d (x, y) \geq 0 $$
My question is: can we define a metric using $(1) $, $(2)$, and $(4) $? Or, equivalently, can we prove $(3) $ (usually called the triangle inequality) from $(1)$, $(2) $ and $(4)$?

Comment: Not even sure that you can prove 4 from 1, 2 and 3

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_spaces#Definition

Answer (score 0):

Take the $S=\{a,b,c\}$ and define

$$d(a,b)=d(b,a)=1,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  d(a,c)=d(c,a)=1,$$

$$d(c,b)=d(b,c)=3,$$

and $$d(a,a)=d(b,b)=d(c,c)=0.$$

This function satisfies (1), (2), and (4), but not (3). Therefore (3) cannot be deduced, unless everything else can be deduced too.

Of course, there is a problem with the question. You said "can we define a metric ... ?" But metric by definition satisfies (4). I take it you really wanted a function $d$ with those properties.

Comment: On your second to last sentence, check out the link in my comment to my own question.

Comment: @user132181 Yes, I have seen the definition of metric many times. The answer to your questions still is the same. No, you cannot deduce (3), from (1), (2), and (4). And the reason is because you can have functions, as above, that satisfy (1), (2), and (4), but not satisfying (3).

Comment: @PiOverTwo I have corrected $d(b,c)=d(b,c)=0$ and $d(a,b)=d(b,b)=...=0$: do you agree with the edit?